# CMake Android cross compiling: clang always try to link with gcc toolchain

Tags: android, cmake, clang, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build my CMake project to Android platform. I used CMake 3.12.3 and ninja 1.9.0, and belowing is the toolchain file I used:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "Android")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK "C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI "arm64-v8a")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION "clang")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE "c++_static")
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/platforms/android-24/arch-arm64")
set(CMAKE_C_ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX "${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/aarch64-linux-android")
set(CMAKE_CXX_ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX "${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/aarch64-linux-android")
```

It fails at configuration stage:

```
Android: Targeting API '24' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and processor 'aarch64'
Android: Selected Clang toolchain 'aarch64-linux-android-clang' with GCC toolchain ''
The C compiler identification is Clang 8.0.7
The CXX compiler identification is Clang 8.0.7
Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: D:/projects/MyProject-android-arm64-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"D:/development/ninja-1.9.0/ninja.exe" "cmTC_70fcb"
    [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_70fcb.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_70fcb

    FAILED: cmTC_70fcb 

    cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.0.5594570\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains//prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/platforms/android-24/arch-arm64 -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes -D__ANDROID_API__=24 -fexceptions  -g  -fPIE -pie -Wl,--gc-sections CMakeFiles/cmTC_70fcb.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_70fcb   && cd ."

    ld: error: unable to find library -lgcc

    ld: error: unable to find library -lgcc

    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

I noticed two unexpected behavior:

1. Although I specified `CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` to **clang**, it still wants to use GCC libraries.
2. Although I specified C and CXX toolchain prefix, It still failed to to find binutils such as  `CMAKE_OBJDUMP`, `CMAKE_STRIP`, `CMAKE_OBJCOPY`, `CMAKE_NM`.

So how should I make everything work?

Comment: Code is checking for these libraries `unable to find library -lgcc`

Comment: "... it still wants to use GCC libraries." - As far as I understand, this is correct. What seems to be not correct is a selected `--gcc-toolchaing` equal to `C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/toolchains//prebuilt/windows-x86_64`. It was several issues with CMake about configuring NDK, probably your case is one of those. Empty string in `with GCC toolchain ''` smells a lot.